# TypeError: Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider is not a constructor?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, rpc, websocket

Trying to connect to a geth machine over websocket?
JS code.

```
var Web3=require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://10.244.5.43:8546'));
console.log(web3.isConnected());
```

Not sure how to connect using WebSocket?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with `web3 v1.0.0 beta 30`. Never got to the bottom of it but skipping the provider construction appeared to fix it:

```
var Web3=require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3('ws://10.244.5.43:8546');
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to wrap Web3 object inside {}

```
const {Web3}  = require('web3')
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're using a version of Web3.js older than 1.0. I believe that the `WebsocketProvider` was added in 1.0.

Comment: Same issue with 1.3.4 (via TypeScript but I doubt it changed something)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

```
let { Web3 } = require("web3");

let provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545");

let web3 = new Web3(provider);

console.log(web3);
```

Answer (score 0):

So in my particular case, I'm using TypeScript and it appears the typings were misleading. The package `web3-providers-ws` says that the following import should be valid:

```
import { WebsocketProvider } from "web3-providers-ws"

const provider = new WebsocketProvider("<host>", { ... })
```

It seems the typings lies a bit (or at least, there is something else that prevent it to work as expected).

I had to do the following to overcome the problem:

```
import WebsocketProvider from "web3-providers-ws"

// @ts-ignore It appears default export is required otherwise it throws 'WebsocketProvider is not a constructor error', the typings says otherwise but well ...
const provider = new WebsocketProvider("<host>", { ... })
```

I tried to play with various `tsconfig.json` options around module and default imports, but did not succeed. Not sure what is not working yet, but at least I have a workaround.

Hopefully it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

For my case only needed to wrap Web3 object inside {} aslo

```
const {Web3}  = require('web3')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).